# List positioning wrong on privileges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, privileges-page

On the [privileges page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges), the list with the privilege stages on the right is all the way down, which shouldn't (and didn't use to) be the case. Clicking on some of the specific privilege stages didn't change anything, i.e. the list on the right always starts *after* the description.

Happens to me on Windows 7 with FF 10.0.2, Safari 5.1.2 and IE 9.0.

[image]

Edit: This problem prevails in FF 12.0 on Win 7.

Comment: Also on FF 10.0.2 and Safari 5.1.2 on Mac OS 10.6.

Comment: Also on very old FF 3.5.15 on Fedora 12, which probably makes it a really general problem...

Comment: FF12.0 @ Win XP, too.

Comment: Confirmed with Opera 11 and 12 (beta), Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem does not appear anymore on Win7 with Firefox 14.0.1, Safari 5.1.7, IE 9.0. Unless anybody else still has this problem, it seems to be solved.

Answer (score 4):

I also happens on FF12 on Ubuntu 12.04.

It's a CSS issue. `div#sidebar`'s width is set to `body.privileges-page#sidebar` width of 240px (plus 60px left margin), while `div#content` (wich contain `#question` and `#sidebar`) has a width of 958px (#question is set to `div.content-inside.post-text`'s width of 660px).

Someone should probably edit the css to change it to:

```
body.privileges-page #sidebar{width:238px;}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem is solved now by looking at the CSS?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be solved to me.